# Givens QR decomposition in R or C++: poor performance (or lack thereof) for rectangular matrices

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, r

My own **Givens**-based QR decomposition function in R (pseudocode from Politecnico of Turin's math department) is the following:

```
>Givens.fn<-function(V) {

   tol<-1.0*10^-14
   m<-dim(V)[1]
   n<-dim(V)[2]

   spId<-bandSparse(m,m,0,list(rep(1, m+1))) # computed just once 
   Q<-spId                                   
   R<-V
   sapply(1:n, function(j){                      
      if (j<m) {    
         vapply((j+1):m, function(i){          # vectorized internal loop  
         if(abs(R[i,j])>tol) {                             
            G<-spId                  
            x<-R[j,j]
            y<-R[i,j]
            norm<-sqrt(x^2+y^2)
            c<-x/norm
            s<-y/norm
            G[j,j]=c
            G[i,i]=c
            G[j,i]=s
            G[i,j]=-s                         
            Q<<-G%*%Q
            R<<-G%*%R
         } 
         return(1)                   # --> saves 15% execution time!
      },FUN.VALUE=1.0)
   }
})

Q<-t(Q)

return(list(Q,R))
}
```

It works fine, but the *givens(*) function provided in R by *pracma* is 134x faster on an total elapsed time around 10" (on my intel i5-3570 4core, 8GB desktop):

```
>m<-20; n<-20
>set.seed(1)
>X <- as.matrix(replicate(n, runif(m)))
>library(rbenchmark)
>library(pracma)
>benchmark(Givens.fn(X),
           givens(X),
           order = "elapsed",
           replications = 10)

          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2    givens(X)           10    0.08    1.000      0.08     0.00         NA        NA
1 Givens.fn(X)           10   10.77  134.625     10.69     0.08         NA        NA
```

Unfortunately, the pracma version accepts just square matrices, which is not my case. Any further code improvements? Any other Givens-based QR functions (even in C++)? Thanks.

Comment: What is QR? Is it related to QR codes? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: All the 3 ways to compute QR decomposition are well described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)

Comment: As I said: please [edit] the question to include this information. A comment is the wrong place for it.

Comment: Could you perhaps remove the leading `>` from your code? This about syntax errors when pasting the code.

Comment: You could also format your code according to the Tidyverse convention. This way, the reviewers can focus on the interesting part of the code instead of complainingthatthecodeisunreadablebecauseofmissingspaces.

Comment: Why don't you use the R base function `qr`?